# Priority in Queue is behaving wierdly in Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I implemented Dijkstra's algorithm with priority queue. Everything works perfectly except for this one special instance of the test case and I don't understand how the priority queue is not working. For some background, in my application I turn input in the form of (row, column) into a node and each row and column are nodes bi-directional. The main bug happens when i run this algorithm with an test input and the priority queue pick a node with a distance of 99999 instead of 4! What i mean by this is that when i compare nodes for the priority, they implement a comparable that looks at the distance (between current node and source node). All un-visited nodes are set to 999999(infinity). Therefore, nodes that are visited will be chosen to be the next current node instead of some random node in the graph.

The following code is Dijkstra's algorithm implemented by priority queue.
[The project on github.](https://github.com/CedricLeong/AlgorithmsProject)

```
public static void execute(int source){
      PriorityQueue<Vertex> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();

        // Set the first node as source node 
        int diameter =0;
        existingVertex.get(source).setDistance(0);

        // Add all nodes into a heap
        pQueue.addAll(existingVertex);
            while (!pQueue.isEmpty()){

                    // Take out first node
                    Vertex n = pQueue.remove();
                    n.setVisited(true);
                    System.out.println("current node=" + n.id);

                    for (Edge e: n.getOutgoingEdges()){
                            Vertex adjNode = e.getDestination();
                            System.out.println("adjNode id=" +adjNode.id);
                            Integer newPossiblePathCost = 1+ n.getDistance();
                            if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(adjNode.isVisited())) {

                            if (newPossiblePathCost<adjNode.getDistance()){
                             adjNode.setDistance(newPossiblePathCost); 
                             System.out.println("Distance:" + adjNode.distance);
                                    // update
                             pQueue.remove(adjNode);
                             pQueue.add(adjNode);}}
                    }

                    // Save the diameter of the traversed graph
                    if(n.getDistance() > diameter  && n.getDistance() != 999999)
                    {
                        diameter = n.getDistance();
                    }
            }       

            diameterlist.add(diameter);

    }
```

Test Case:

  1 14
  1 2
  2 15
  3 15
  4 15
  5 15
  6 15
  7 15
  8 15
  9 15
  10 15
  11 15
  12 15
  13 15

Output:

1. current node=14
2. adjNode id=1
3. Distance:1
4. current node=1
5. adjNode id=14
6. adjNode id=2
7. Distance:2
8. current node=2
9. adjNode id=1
10. adjNode id=15
11. Distance:3
12. **current node=13**
13. adjNode id=15
14. current node=15

Could anyone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: What did you learn when you used a debugger?

Comment: side note: '999999' is not infinity, to make your code more easy to read you may use some built-in constant such as [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: Hold on i'm using the debugger

Comment: Apparantly the distances for node 13 was 100 vs 101. I wasn't comfortable using a debugger but I see it's usefulness now. Thanks.